# java servlet response to range request fails

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers

I am trying to create a media server that can fulfill range requests. Initially, without partial content(sending the full video data), the server worked. However, now it is not working. I am able to get the start and end index of the range header. I am receiving the response status and response type in the browser but not the other headers and the response body.

Here is the code:

```
String range = request.getHeader("Range") ;
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(path , "r") ;
                    if(range != null) {
                        range = range.trim().substring("range=".length()) ;
                        String [] index = range.split("-") ;
                        byte [] buffer = new byte[2048] ;
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()) ;
                        if(index.length > 1) {
                            long start = Long.parseLong(index[0]) ;
                            long end = Long.parseLong(index[1]) ;
                            long contentLength = end - start + 1 ;
                            System.out.println("start: " + start);
                            System.out.println("end: " + end);
                            if(start < file.length() && end < file.length() && end > start) {
                                response.setContentType(type);
                                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
                                file.seek(start);
                                long bytesleft = contentLength ; 
                                while(file.getFilePointer() <= end) {
                                    if(bytesleft >= buffer.length) {
                                        file.readFully(buffer);
                                        dos.write(buffer);
                                        dos.flush();
                                        bytesleft = bytesleft - buffer.length ;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        file.readFully(buffer , 0 , (int) bytesleft);
                                        dos.write(buffer , 0 , (int) bytesleft);
                                        dos.flush();
                                    }
                                }
                                response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                                response.setContentLengthLong(contentLength);
                                response.setHeader("Content-Range", new StringBuilder("bytes ").append(start).append("-").append(end).append("/").append(file.length()).toString());
                            }
                            else {
                                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
                            }
                        }
                        else {

                            long start = Long.parseLong(index[0]) ;
                            long end = file.length() - 1 ;
                            long contentLength = end - start + 1 ;
                            System.out.println("start: " + start);
                            System.out.println("end: " + end);
                            if(start < file.length()) {
                                response.setContentType(type);
                                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
                                file.seek(start);
                                long bytesleft = contentLength ; 
                                while(file.getFilePointer() <= end) {
                                    if(bytesleft >= buffer.length) {
                                        file.readFully(buffer);
                                        dos.write(buffer);
                                        dos.flush();
                                        bytesleft = bytesleft - buffer.length ;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        file.readFully(buffer , 0 , (int) bytesleft);
                                        dos.write(buffer , 0 , (int) bytesleft);
                                        dos.flush();
                                    }
                                }
                                response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                                response.setContentLengthLong(contentLength);
                                response.setHeader("Content-Range", new StringBuilder("bytes ").append(start).append("-").append(end).append("/").append(file.length()).toString());
                            }
                            else {
                                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    file.close();
```

output is:

```
start: 0
end: 43541165
```

Comment: Any error or exception that you see?

Comment: No, there are no exceptions or errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the mistake. Basically, I should have set the headers before writing the file content and now it successfully works.

Here is the new code:

```
String range = request.getHeader("Range") ;
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(path , "r") ;
                    if(range != null) {
                        range = range.trim().substring("range=".length()) ;
                        String [] index = range.split("-") ;
                        byte [] buffer = new byte[2048] ;
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()) ;
                        if(index.length > 1) {
                            long start = Long.parseLong(index[0]) ;
                            long end = Long.parseLong(index[1]) ;
                            long contentLength = end - start + 1 ;
                            System.out.println("start: " + start);
                            System.out.println("end: " + end);
                            if(start < file.length() && end < file.length() && end > start) {
                                response.setContentType(type);
                                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
                                response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                                response.setContentLengthLong(contentLength);
                                response.setHeader("Content-Range", new StringBuilder("bytes ").append(start).append("-").append(end).append("/").append(file.length()).toString());
                                file.seek(start);
                                long bytesleft = contentLength ; 
                                while(file.getFilePointer() <= end) {
                                    if(bytesleft >= buffer.length) {
                                        file.readFully(buffer);
                                        dos.write(buffer);
                                        dos.flush();
                                        bytesleft = bytesleft - buffer.length ;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        file.readFully(buffer , 0 , (int) bytesleft);
                                        dos.write(buffer , 0 , (int) bytesleft);
                                        dos.flush();
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
                            }
                        }
                        else {

                            long start = Long.parseLong(index[0]) ;
                            long end = file.length() - 1 ;
                            long contentLength = end - start + 1 ;
                            System.out.println("start: " + start);
                            System.out.println("end: " + end);
                            if(start < file.length()) {
                                response.setContentType(type);
                                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
                                response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                                response.setContentLengthLong(contentLength);
                                response.setHeader("Content-Range", new StringBuilder("bytes ").append(start).append("-").append(end).append("/").append(file.length()).toString());
                                file.seek(start);
                                long bytesleft = contentLength ; 
                                while(file.getFilePointer() <= end) {
                                    if(bytesleft >= buffer.length) {
                                        file.readFully(buffer);
                                        dos.write(buffer);
                                        dos.flush();
                                        bytesleft = bytesleft - buffer.length ;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        file.readFully(buffer , 0 , (int) bytesleft);
                                        dos.write(buffer , 0 , (int) bytesleft);
                                        dos.flush();
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    file.close();
```